# how to use if else to print data to the screen in nextflow?

Tags: bioinformatics, nextflow

I Have a problem right there. So when i writing the nextflow workflow, I want it run automatically every step. like what happen if reads low quality, adapter ... So i think I can use the **if else** to solve this problem. But unlucky ỉ realize that the workflow nextflow running not like python. This mean every process must be contact together, if not the process will be running together at the same time. my question is how can i control step by step like python ? here is some example:

```
workflow {
    read_pairs_ch = Channel.fromFilePairs(params.reads)
    FASTQC(read_pairs_ch)
    trimmomatic(read_pairs_ch)
    FASTQC_1(trimmomatic.out)
    FASTQC_1.out
        .map { sample, fastqc -> sample }
        .collect()
        .set { ready_ch }
    FASTQC_check(ready_ch) 

// when all process done do this

    if (FASTQC_check.out)
      Channel
        .fromPath('/home/dungnguyen/genepanel/bin/data3.txt')
        .splitText()
        .view { 
              println it 
          }
    else
      println "404 .. something went wrong"
```

i want to use **if** when every process is done but it run same time with FASTQC. i don't know how to control this. Someone help me please?

Another problem is that the next thread can print the screen on yes or no question? This means I want to keep using to call the variant, if the data is of low quality but the user still wants to run...

Comment: Can you describe a bit more about what your goal is? I.e. What are you trying to achieve? Why print the contents of data3.txt to console at the end of your workflow? Note that Nextflow has the [`onComplete`](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/metadata.html#completion-handler) event handler to more formally indicate workflow success.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, the bottom part of your workflow block would be a process. Then, usually, processes wait for each other because they depend on input/output from each other. If you want a process to wait for other processes to finish before it starts, even if they don't share inputs/outputs, you can create [state dependency](https://nextflow-io.github.io/patterns/state-dependency/).

Check the snippet below (pay attention to the value they share, even if it's not used by the process):

```
process foo {
    output: 
    val true
    script:
    """
    echo your_command_here
    """
}

process bar {
    input: 
    val ready
    path fq
    script:
    """
    echo other_commad_here --reads $fq
    """
}

workflow {
    reads_ch = Channel.fromPath("$baseDir/data/reads/11010*.fq.gz", checkIfExists:true)

    foo()
    bar(foo.out, reads_ch)
}
```

If you don't want to create a process for the last part of your workflow block, you can use the `collect` channel operator (check the [official documentation](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#collect) for details) in your if expression. It'll block until all the output channels you're collecting are done.

PS: I agree with Steve above that what you're trying to do seems to be what's usually done with the `onComplete` event handler.